# about the usage of modulus operator

Tags: java, data-structures

this a part of code for Quick Sort algorithm but realy I do not know that why it uses `rand() %n`  please help me thanks

```
Swap(V,0,rand() %n)  // move pivot elem to V[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used for randomizing the Quick Sort to achieve an average of nlgn time complexity.

To Quote from Wikipedia:

> **What makes random pivots a good choice?**
>
> Suppose we sort the list and then
>   divide it into four parts. The two
>   parts in the middle will contain the
>   best pivots; each of them is larger
>   than at least 25% of the elements and
>   smaller than at least 25% of the
>   elements. If we could consistently
>   choose an element from these two
>   middle parts, we would only have to
>   split the list at most 2log2n times
>   before reaching lists of size 1,
>   yielding an  algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Quick sort has its average time complexity O(nlog(n)) but worst case complexity is n^2 (when array is already sorted). So to make it O(nlog(n)) pivot is chosen randomly so rand()%n is generating a random index between 0 to n-1.